# SQL create query based on data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, union

I have a SQL Server database where I would like to take one main table that has columns that contain IDs and join? them with 3 other tables where those IDs match actual names.

Example

Table = slips looks like this:

```
ID | UserID | ClientID | TimeID
---------------------------------
10 |   35   |    48    |   27
```

I have 3 other tables called `Usernames, Clientnames, Timeactnames`

Each one of those tables looks like this:

Usernames

```
ID | Nickname1 |
----------------
35 |   Shawn   |
```

Clientnames

```
ID | Nickname1 |
----------------
48 |   Roger   |
```

Timeactnames

```
ID | Nickname1 |
----------------
27 |   Filing  |
```

I'd like to have a new query result that shows the slip table results like this:

```
ID | UserID | ClientID | TimeID
---------------------------------
10 | Shawn  |  Roger   |  Filing
```

Is this possible?

I have tried Joins and Unions but I never get that result I get some massive huge table combination of results:

```
SELECT tsslips.*, ClientData.*, UserData.*, TimeActData.* FROM slips JOIN ClientData ON ClientData.ID = slips.ClientID JOIN TSUserData ON UserData.ID = slips.UserID JOIN TimeActData ON TimeActData.ID = slips.TimeActID
```

And all I got was a really huge long table that had all of the info but not a new merged table like I wanted.

I then tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT UserID, ClientID, TimeActID FROM Slips UNION ALL SELECT Nickname1 FROM ClientData UNION ALL SELECT Nickname1 FROM UserData UNION ALL SELECT Nickname1 FROM TimeActData ) all_tables WHERE all_tables.ClientID = 'something'
```

But I don't think I formatted or used that one correctly since I got an error that said:

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I'm trying to get query result so that I can use the right click save as to CSV option in SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.ID, u.NickName1 As UserID, c.NickName1 As ClientID, t.NickName1 As TimeID
FROM Slips s
LEFT JOIN Username u ON u.ID = s.UserID
LEFT JOIN ClientNames c ON c.ID = s.ClientID
LEFT JOIN TimeactNames t on t.ID = s.TimeID
```

Depending on your data, you may want INNER JOINs instead of LEFT JOINs.

Comment: This worked great but is it possible to get the rest of the column data on the slip table? right now the new end result query shows exactly what we asked it to join which is great but I would love to have other fields from the slip table that we aren't joining. For example there is a column labeled Description | Time spent | Date | 

Those fields I would like to have in addition to the joined data fields. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Just include those fields in the select list: s.Description, s.Timespent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT Slips.ID,Usernames.Nickname1 AS UnserID,Clientnames
      ,Nickname1 AS ClientID
      ,Timeactnames.Nickname1 AS TimeId
FROM Slips 
LEFT JOIN Usernames ON Slips.UserId = Usernames.ID
LEFT JOIN Clientnames ON Slips.ClientId = Clientnames.ID
LEFT JOIN Timeactnames ON Slips.TimeId = Timeactnames.ID
```

Comment: thank you for the help! I was able to get what I needed using another method mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

Is this like something you are looking for?
    Select slips.ID, Usernames.Nickname1, Clientnames.Nickname1, Timeactnames.Nickname1
    FROM slips, Usernames, Clientnames, Timeactnames
    WHERE slips.UserID=Usernames.ID, slips.ClientID=Clientnames.ID, slips.TimeID=Timeactnames.ID;

Comment: thank you for the help! I was able to get what I needed using another method mentioned above.